# How to access an array within a nested ngFor loop that is from another page?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, ngfor

I have a page, which we'll call **Object List**.

The **Object List** page shows a list of items, which are selectable.

Selecting an object passes the user to a new view (**Object Details**) using the navCtrl. The navCtrl passes the object using `(Object: object)`

Object contains a name, details, and an Array of genres.

On the **Object Details** page, information about the object is displayed.

```
<html>{{object.name}}</html
<html>{{object.details}}</html>
...
```

At this point, I am trying to iterate through an array of genres. Each genre has a description.

So, I have tried the following without success:

```
<div *ngFor="let genre of object.genres">
    <h1>{{genre.description}}</h1>
</div>
```

Here, I am getting a `description is undefined` error.

Any ideas?

Edit: Here are my objects

```
Object {
    gameid: number
    name: text
    details: text
    genres: Array<Genre>
}

Genre {
    genreid: number
    description: text
}
```

Comment: can you post your data please, also just a wild guess can you try using safe operator i:e {{genre?.description}} and try

Comment: What sort of other data do you need? Data is a loose term.

Comment: How does your object look like can you try the elvis operation i mentioned does it work

Comment: The Elvis operator doesn't work.

Comment: How are you passibg info to the child component using @input?

Comment: this.navCtrl.push(ObjectDetailsPage, { Object: object });

Comment: Can you make use of input to pass info to child, not used navctrl before its a ionic thing i suppose